No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public (NODEJS v4)
I am getting this error and stuck on this
(using v4 and nodejs v20.14.0 and     "@azure/functions": "^4.5.0",  "durable-functions": "^3.1.0")
I have tried
1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-troubleshoot?pivots=nodejs-model-v4


2) updating host.json 
"extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
    }


3.  updating local.settings.json  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",


4. updating /azure-functions-core-tool to latest

Still I am stuck on this issue my functions dont load

Where's your function.json file? And did you export the function properly? Your screenshot doesn't show it.

we dont need function.json for v4
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-upgrade-v4?tabs=v4&pivots=programming-language-javascript @ArchitectJamie

I saw the title and directory tree in the screenshot and jumped the gun. My apologies. Have you tried deploying this to an Azure function? This would be a good test whether the issue is either code related or environment related.

can i check before deploying @ArchitectJamie

also how can i track code related issue as im not able to see logs @ArchitectJamie

The reason I suggest deploying it to Azure, as a test, is to eliminate factors associated with your local environment, as opposed to it being an issue with the project or code. Doing this and going to the functions section for your app in the Portal will verify that the runtime was able to identify the individual functions. You can see logs here too. Also, for local, change the log level to trace to get more logs out of func (sets the --verbose switch).

@art, Please share your code if possible.

Which part of  code @PravallikaKV

I printed the logs with verbose it gives same thing 0 function loaded @ArchitectJamie

@art I think we need to see an example where you have a client function - something with a binding which can trigger an orchestration / activity, like http trigger or something.

I was missing this
Add a main property to the package.json with a glob that matches the functions in your project; in my case dist/src/functions/*/index.js -
Great article
https://johnnyreilly.com/migrating-azure-functions-node-js-v4-typescript
